# SQL with the device level Opt in and Out

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have SQL running from a Data extension where I have all marketing opted in contacts, now I need to add a field to the SQL with the device level Opt in and Out options as I will further use these in a journey, where customers who opted in will receive a push and those who opted out will get an email.

I'm not sure how to write this query. I wanted to join it with _PushAddress data view table but it doesn't have a Subscriber key to match it with the Subscriber key. I could perhaps join it with a Filtered Mobile List but the mobile list that I created with filters: OptedIn=2 and OptedOut=1, it doesn't have Subscriber key so I cannot match it with my data extension. My SQL query looks like this for the time being:

```sql
SELECT
a.Email
a.Campaign
a.Subscriberkey
b.OptIn
b.OptOut
FROM DataExtension1
INNER JOIN
...
```

we have.Subscriberkey=...

Comment: You can use /contacts/v1/attributes/search REST API to retrieve contacts that with mobile number starts with x, it returns array of contacts with contactId, contactKey and mobile number, parse the result and insert into a DE then join with your DE1 on contactKey and join _pushAddress on contactId. I don’t think there is a data view for contacts. _subscriber data view is only for email studio related contacts. So rest api will be your best bet